# htaccess rewrite give error 500 in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been searching on the web but nothing seems to work. I'm working in local with Apache and Xampp. I have created an .htaccess file and rewrote all urls ending with .php and .html to remove the extension and I have created a custom 404 page. Everything worked fine. However, now I'm trying to rewrite a dynamic url that looks like

`/TotinCoblan/update/Wine?id=2`

to

`/TotinCoblan/update/Wine/2`

and I keep getting error 500. this is my .htaccess file. From what I understood,

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

should avoid infinite loops.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/update/Wine/([0-9]+)/?$ /update/Wine?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 TotinCoblan/errors/404
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /TotinCoblan/errors/404

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^update/Wine/([0-9]+)/?$ /update/Wine?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked pretty well. However I realized my css files were not being loaded correctly so I had to use absolute path in all my files.

Comment: Yes it is always better to use absolute paths for css/js/images. If it worked consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `-f` checks to use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}${REQUEST_URI}` instead. The problem with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is that mod_rewrite will partially attempt to map the URI to a file, and it accounts for PATH INFO, which means if the request is something like:

```
/something/foo/anything/
```

and you happen to have an existing file/script at:

```
/something/foo.php
```

then the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` check **will be true**, and the URI that it assumes you meant is:

```
/something/foo.php/anything/
```

And, like your code is doing, the `.php` is appended to the end instead:

```
/something/foo/anything/.php
```

and that causes the infinite loop. Try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/update/Wine/([0-9]+)/?$ /update/Wine?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 TotinCoblan/errors/404
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code but I got 404 errors without the .php and .html files... the code below worked in those cases too. Thanks

Comment: @amunte sorry, the `$` is supposed to be a `%`

Answer (score 0):

I finally used this code, I had to use RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f since the page was loading only after reloading two time. With that instructions loads the first time.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
ErrorDocument 404 /TotinCoblan/errors/404

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^update/Wine/([0-9]+)/?$ update/Wine.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```